# How to call Go function from Python

Tags: python, go, .so

I am trying to call go lang function from python 
when I call my python program I am seeing the following error.
I am referring to the [Go to pythn](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) link.

[image: error]

Python Program

```
    from ctypes import *
    def call_go_function():

        lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./awesome.so")
        lib.Add.argtypes = [c_longlong, c_longlong]
        print( lib.Add(12,99)) 

    call_go_function()
```

Go Program

```
package main
import "C"
import (

"sync"
 )
 var count int
 var mtx sync.Mutex
 //export Add
 func Add(a, b int) int { return a + b }
 func main() {}
```

Comment: You are using Windows, the tutorial you are following uses Linux/Unix. Perhaps you can apply the tutorial in a Docker container or VM.

Comment: Please don't include images of text. They are hard to read (and impossible to read if you rely on a screen reader), and they are not searchable and cannot be indexed. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python path it looks like this is a 32-bit Python version. You cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit user-space code.

So I guess you need to either:

- Rebuild your Go code as a 32-bit DLL (see GOARCH=386) or
- Install and run a 64-bit Python version.

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe it's an environment. Try running a simple program.

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./func.so")
r=lib.fun(10,20)
print(r)
```

```
package main
import "C"
//export fun
func fun(x int,y int) int{
    return x+y
}

func main(){}
```

```
>go build -o func.so -buildmode=c-shared func.go
>python test.py
30
```